# Reading a character in an istream pointer

Tags: c++

I have a class that takes an istream pointer and reads the objects one by one. Though whenever I try to read a character I get the following

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type& {aka char&}’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type {aka char}’
```

the function that takes in the istream looks like this

```
void foo(istream *is){
    while(is->get(ch)){
       // do something
    }
}
```

And I am passing down the istream like this

```
istream is(cin.rdbuf());
reader.foo(&is);
```

Comment: Which type is ch ?

Comment: ch is unsigned char

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve], then edit your question to include at least the declaration of ch.

Comment: The function is expecting a `char&` but you're passing an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `ch`, it is of the wrong type (As you mentioned in the comments); [`std::basic_istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) expects a value of type `char` (Since that is what `std::basic_istream::char_type` is defined as), but passing it a value with type `unsigned char` creates the error. Change the type to `char` to solve your problem.

Here is some minimal code that exhibits the example working:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(istream* is){
    char ch;
    while(is->get(ch)){
       // do something
       break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    istream is(cin.rdbuf());
    foo(&is);
}
```

On a side note, I would make the recommendation that you avoid using pointers in this case, and instead use references, since that achieves the same purpose, except that it looks cleaner.

Comment: Sadly I have to use pointers. Part of my assignment is not changing the parameters taken by the function